# Highlight exception throwers in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I recently moved from Eclipse to IntelliJ IDEA, and there is a feature that I'm missing. In Eclipse, when you placed the caret on a checked exception, in throws declaration or catch block, it would highlight which method/constructor calls throw that exception.

Is there any way to do this in IntelliJ IDEA (Community edition)?

Comment: ... 6 years working in Eclipse and I never knew it did that.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Place the caret on the `catch` keyword and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.

(`Find` | `Highlight Usages in File`). If you are using different keymap and the above shortcut doesn't work, use `Help` | `Find Action` to search for this action and see its keyboard shortcut:

[image: Find Action]

If you want it to work automatically, enable `Settings` | `Editor` | `Highlight usages of element at caret`.

The same works on `try` and `throws` keywords with a choice of exceptions to highlight.

Here is a screenshot from IntelliJ IDEA Tip of the Day:

[image: exceptions highlighted]

Note that there is no way to highlight it by particular exception class until you select this class from the list of suggestions:

[image: exceptions to highlight]

Comment: Still not possible to highlight particular exception today?

Comment: @Wooff only after you select it from the list

Comment: What if there's no catch and just throws ? @CrazyCoder

Comment: For IntelliJ v2016, and maybe earlier versions, the auto-highlight has been turned on by default. Click the `throws` in the method signature or the `catch` to see what is throwing those exceptions.

Comment: In the calling method which has a catch, I cannot seem to see which method throws a particular exception, no matter how many times I press the suggested key. This is way behind the Eclipse behaviour.

Comment: This does not seem to work in intelliJ Idea 2018 community edition. I remember it used to work ealier. Any update on this?