# How to easily add Exception subclasses into catch?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

Let's say I need to add some `Exception` subclasses into `catch`, such as these ones

```
    ...//
    catch (ConnectTimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (HttpHostConnectException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The first two are (obviously) subclasses of [`IOException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/IOException.html).

How can I add such subclasses into `catch` in a better (quicker, easier) way than copy/pasting then?

I am confident that IDEA has such automatic feature, but I am not sure which one it is or how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on `try`, **Detail exceptions**:

[image]

Comment: This one indeed creates a detailed exceptions, but in my case it also removed `ConnectTimeoutException` and `HttpHostConnectException`. They are subclasses of `IOException` so IDEA probably thought I do not need such level of details. Is there a way to look into subclasses of `try` block? Like in my case, I navigate to `IOException`, press "something" and I get a list of `IOException` sublasses.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7774224/104891), it may help you to find what specific exceptions are actually thrown in your code and where. To list subclasses of `IOException` use `Ctrl`+`H` (**Type Hierarchy**).