# Highlight unchecked exception in catch in intelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm in the process of moving to intelliJ from eclipse but I've stumbled upon a highlighting problem with exceptions in catch clauses. This is somewhat linked to [Highlight exception throwers in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773670/highlight-exception-throwers-in-intellij-idea)

Given example code as follows:

```
try {
    System.out.print(Double.parseDouble("throws exception"));
} catch (NumberFormatException e){
    System.out.print(e.toString());
}
```

and positioning the cursor on the `NumberFormatException` in eclipse will highlight where it is thrown as in

[image]

but in intelliJ I haven't been able to reproduce this: [image]

I've tried `highlight usage in file` when placing the caret on both the catch and the `NumberFormatException` but it doesn't work, what am I doing wrong?

It is the same when doing it in the method signature,
eclipse:

[image]

but not in intelliJ

[image]

Is it possible to get this in the same way as in eclipse?

**EDIT**

As explained by yole in one of the answers this is specific to unchecked exceptions in IntelliJ even if they are declared in the method signature as in the case for `Double.parseDouble(String) throws NumberFormatException()`

Comment: I think you can configure it for the throws thing but not for the catch, like in your first code example. Perhaps this is your penance for using an lesser IDE for all this time!

Comment: Here's the throws case in action so that does work: http://i.imgur.com/zdt3C8B.png

Comment: @pvg http://i.imgur.com/twlY7zk.png Doing it for checked exceptions seem to work but not for unchecked, I can get it to work as intended by **throwing IOEx's** but **not with NPEx's** as in the image I linked by placing cursor on throws. Is there something I'm missing behind the reasoning for this?

Comment: Does it work in Eclipse for unchecked exceptions? How can it possibly know what what unchecked exceptions are thrown?

Comment: How is your question different from the [one you have linked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773670/highlight-exception-throwers-in-intellij-idea)? It has the valid answer how it works in IntelliJ IDEA and you were given the same answer here.

Comment: @pvg a NumberFormatException is an unchecked Exception, and you can see in the pictures that eclipse highlights it without a problem.

Comment: @CrazyCoder as yole pointed out in the answer below it only works for checked exceptions but the linked question does not state it doesn't work for unchecked so it is not the same question

Comment: NumberFormatException, while an RTE is explicitly defined in throws clauses in the relevant JDK apis. RTEs in general are not, though.

Answer (score 5):

In IntelliJ IDEA, to see where an exception is thrown, you need to put the caret on the `catch` keyword, not on the exception class name.

Comment: There should be an option called "Highlight usages of element at caret".

Comment: "I've tried highlight usage in file when placing the caret on both the catch and the NumberFormatException but it doesn't work" I did :) but maybe this is related to the type of exception as in my comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42672360/highlight-exception-in-catch-in-intellij/42673959#comment72476749_42672360 ?

Comment: Indeed, this works only for checked exceptions. An unchecked exception can be thrown by any expression, so I'm not sure what you expect to be highlighted.

Comment: @yole I was expecting it to highlight expressions that explicitly declares that it throws an unchecked exception, i.e a NullPointerException or a NumberFormatException in the case of Double.parseDouble(String), but then I presume this is working as intended and not a setting I have missed turning on/off?

Comment: No, there is no setting for this.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you need a key-combination: `Ctrl + Shift + F7`

See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206269539-how-can-I-see-in-intellij-where-exception-is-thrown-

Comment: `Highlight usage in file` is the `Ctrl + Shift +F7` shortcut but it doesn't work

Comment: Look for "Highlight usages of element at caret"